# Can I run out of gas while fast-traveling?

Tags: final-fantasy-15

This question is pretty self-explanatory. Gas seems to only go down while driving manually or automatically, but since fast-traveling also relocates the Regalia, it only makes sense that Noctis and co. are driving the Regalia during this time. I haven't experimented enough with fast-traveling much as of yet, since playing other games while auto-piloting across the world to get lazy AP has been my strategy lately, so I'm not sure if it's possible to run out of gas while fast-traveling.

If this can happen, does the game tell you? Or is it just not possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.

Gas doesn't deplete during a fast travel as far as I've been able to determine, however you can only fast travel to locations visited previously by driving to them.

The game does tell you when you're out of gas but I have not seen anything warn me other than the tank meter, or heard any of my other party notify / warn / whine about gas level.

Comment: Delete -> deplete, I think. (I would edit but it's not enough characters.)

Comment: Fixed, I was answering from my phone so my typos increase exponentially.

Comment: No worries, I always post on my phone so I know how it is.  It was obviously just a typo. As for that second part of your post, I actually had Ignis comment that we were "practically running on fumes" when I hit a quarter tank. There was another time that my gas gauge was the tiniest sliver and nobody ever commented, so it's definitely not something you can count on.

Comment: Well they nailed how fickle friends can be, that's for sure.